# Does halfling luck apply to death saving throws?

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw, character-death, racial-traits, halfling

The rule states that halfling luck applies to saving throws and the death rolls are called "death saving throws."  Based on that I decided to allow it.  Additionally, I thought allowing halfling luck on death saving throws was also within the spirit of the game.  I've been unable to find anything in the rule books that addresses it.

Comment: Related: [What ways (other than advantage) are there to improve the total for a death saving throw?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177073/33569), [How else can I get Advantage on Death Saving Throws?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/86391/33569), [Do Bane/Bless apply to death saving throws?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/168580/33569), [Does a Paladin's Aura of Protection Affect Allies' Death Saving Throws?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/94927/33569)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, the Halfling racial feature Lucky works with death saving throws.

> Whenever you start your turn with 0 hit points, you must
>   make a special saving throw, called a death saving throw,
>   to determine whether you creep closer to death or hang
>   onto life. Unlike other saving throws, this one isn’t tied to
>   any ability score. You are in the hands of fate now, aided
>   only by spells and **features that improve your chances of
>   succeeding on a saving throw**.

Lucky is exactly this, a feature that improves your chances of succeeding on a saving throw.

Even ignoring this (reasonably explicit) statement, a death saving throw is "a special saving throw" - it's pretty clearly a saving throw, and Lucky says that it works on saving throws.

Comment: A death saving throw is a saving throw is a saving throw. My divination wizard will have to remember this as well.