# Do Bane/Bless apply to death saving throws?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, saving-throw

A possibly related Q&A: [Does halfling luck apply to death saving throws?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78944/does-halfling-luck-apply-to-death-saving-throws)

---

The description of the [*Bane*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bane) spell reads (emphasis mine):

> Whenever a target [...] makes an attack roll or **saving throw** before the spell ends, the target must roll a d4 and subtract the number rolled from the attack roll or **saving throw**.

The description of the [*bless*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bless) spell reads similarly.

Based on this text, and the linked question, am I right to assume that these spells apply to death saving throws?

Comment: Related on [Can Bless or Bardic Inspiration help a creature from rolling a 1 on a death save?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/156433)

Comment: Related: [What ways (other than advantage) are there to improve the total for a death saving throw?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177073/33569), [How else can I get Advantage on Death Saving Throws?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/86391/33569), [Does a Paladin's Aura of Protection Affect Allies' Death Saving Throws?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/94927/33569)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Yes, death saving throws are saving throws

Death saving throws are a type of saving throws (right there in the name)<sup>†</sup>, so *bane* and *bless* can affect them. The spells also don't end because the target is at 0 hit points. The only exception is if you are the one casting the spell, because the falling unconscious that happens before making death saves would break your concentration.

---

† For completeness: Death saving throws are defined on page 197 of the PHB, which opens:

> Whenever you start your turn with 0 hit points, you must make a special saving throw, called a death saving throw, [...]